# My Controller isn't found

Tags: php, laravel-5

route in routes.php

```
Route::get('korisnici', array('uses'=>'MojPrviKontroler@prvaAkcija'));
//
```

my controler in Controllers

```
<?php  
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MojPrviKontrolerController extends Controller 
 {
public $restful = true;
public function get_prvaAkcija()
    {
     return View::make('prviViewovi.PrviView.php');

    }

}
```

[image: PICTURE]

Can somebody tell my why my controller isn't found?

Comment: You didn't define the namespace

Comment: doesn't work.
FatalErrorException in MojPrviKontroler.php line 6:
Class 'Controller' not found

Comment: i try trough command line..it says: Controller already exists!

Comment: anybody else? im desperate..

Comment: Doesn't work what? What did you do?

Comment: @FilipVuković I have updated my answer. can you please try adding the namespace?

Comment: @PeeHaa doesn't work anything

Comment: guys ty for help..The problem was   return View::make('prviViewovi.PrviView.php');
maybe what was in laravel 4
return view('PrviView' ); works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a wrong namespace problem.

Change to this:

```
<?php  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
```

Comment: can you try adding the namespace? I have updated the answer. @Filip